# Best way to initiate a pay per month membership scheme

Tags: civimember, recurring-contributions

I’d like to offer a membership scheme whereby you can pay a yearly payment or monthly recurring payments. Is it possible to do this via the membership options or will I have to set up a recurring contribution?

Answer (score 4):

Try by doing this

1. Create a Membership type ABC with monthly rolling with auto renew required option ticked.
2. Create a price set with price field as select or radio with two options

   2.a ABC membership type (monthly) - monthly amount - number of terms set to 1

   2.b ABC membership type (yearly) - yearly amount - number of terms set to 12
3. Include the price set in membership signup form

Or

1. Create a Membership type ABC with monthly rolling with auto renew required option ticked.
2. Create a Membership type ABC-yearly with yearly rolling with auto renew required option ticked.
3. Include both the membership type in membership page

(Second method will work, but not sure about first method)

Comment: I've ran into the issue where doing monthly v yearly memberships need their own contribution page. The auto renew value for a given membership is not correct when using price sets. Civi requires that you include all member types in the same price field.